# Angular Kendo UI Datepicker - Disable two date ranges

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I've seen the docs for creating a function to set a single disabled date range, but I'm trying to disable two ranges (disable all dates before minDate and all dates after maxDate). This is what I'm trying:

```
<kendo-datepicker [disabledDates]="disabledDates"></kendo-datepicker>
```

TS:

```
public disabledDates = (date: Date): boolean => {
return date < this.minDate && date > this.maxDate;
  }
```

I know there's a way to set a min/max range in the html, but that makes the disabled dates disappear. I want to still see the dates as disabled.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it almost exactly like in the code you wrote, only there is a small mistake you made. You need to replace the `&&` with `||`:

```
return date < this.minDate || date > this.maxDate;
```

The two ranges are exclusive so using `&&` returns `false` for every date.